# Problemas em um Select CodeIgniter + PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

Olá, tenho a seguinte caso, tenho um doador que deseja fazer uma doação em um hemocentro, ele faz a busca desse hemocentro e clica em um botão desejo doar aqui. Com isso será criada uma tabela no banco de dados chamada **doação_marcada, com os dados: id_doador, id_hemocentro, turno, data_possivel_doacao** .
Agora quando eu realizo o login no hemocentro na tela inicial deveria aparecer os dados da tabela **doador** que fosse igual ao id_doador da tabela doacao_marcada, além dos outros dados da tabela doação marcada. Mas só está aparecendo os dados do doador. Segue meu select.

```
    $status = 'Aguardando Confirmação';
    $this->db
    ->select("*")
    ->from("doacao_marcada")
    ->where('status_doacao_marcada', $status)
    ->where('id_hemocentro', $this->session->userdata('id_hemocentro'));
    $query = $this->db->get()->result();
    foreach ($query as $row) {
        $this->db->select("*")
        ->from("doador")
        ->where("id_doador", $row->id_doador);
        return $this->db->get()->result();
    }
```

Comment: quando você dá um `return`, a função simplesmente retorna o que está passando ali e para a execução do método, o que não está claro é as informações exatamente que você precisa. Você quer retornar os dados de TODOS os doadores, certo?

Answer (score 1):

Se o relacionamento já existe entre as tabelas, você não precisa fazer uma consulta por vez, você deve fazer um `join` na própria consulta, o que no caso deve ficar assim:

```
$status = 'Aguardando Confirmação';
$this->db
->select("*")
->from("doacao_marcada")
->join("doador", "doacao_marcada.id_doador = doador.id")
->where('status_doacao_marcada', $status)
->where('id_hemocentro', $this->session->userdata('id_hemocentro'));
return $this->db->get()->result();
```